# Disk space not reporting correctly

Tags: itunes, macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

Trying to do a manual backup of a 64Gb iPhone to an Mac Book Pro running Mountain Lion, iTunes stated that there wasn't enough disk space.

I deleted enough files so that Finder reports almost 95Gb free.

[image]

iTunes still states that there isn't enough space. On closer inspection, Disk Utility reports only about 20Gb free.

[image]

I've repaired disk permissions and verified and fixed the disk, booted in Recovery mode, but the reports are still the same.

I should have enough space, but clearly something is wrong here. Can someone please tell me what I can do to get the reporting correct and consistent?

Comment: There is no such thing as an iMac Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have automatic Time Machine backups on:

Try to disable automatic Time Machine backup

Wait 5 minutes,
Then try again

When you're done enable Time Machine again

Comment: You're a genius! That worked; any idea why Time Machine is causing this?

Comment: Time Machine snapshots: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015

Comment: `Finder and Get Info windows don't include them in their calculations.` - that's poor design. Thanks ;O)